# Que signifient ces dictons sur la Sainte-Catherine ?

Tags: sens, proverbes

Le dicton « à la Sainte-Catherine, tout bois prend racine » est bien connu. Mais que signifient les dictons suivants ?

1. À la Sainte-Catherine, les sardines tournent l'échine ; à la Saint-Blaise, elles reparaissent.
2. À la Sainte-Catherine, l'hiver s'aberline ; à la Saint-André, il est aberliné.
3. Pour la Sainte-Catherine, fais de la farine ; car pour Saint-André, le bief sera gelé.
4. Pour la Sainte-Catherine, le porc couine.
5. Sainte-Catherine, amène la couétine.
6. Sainte-Catherine, amène la farine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il est à noter avant tout que [sainte Catherine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherine%20d'Alexandrie) se fête le 25 novembre, à la fin des beaux jours et à l'approche de l'hiver.

1. [Saint Blaise](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaise%20de%20S%C3%A9baste) se fête le 3 février. Or, les sardines se reproduisent le plus souvent [de novembre à février](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardine#Reproduction). Cette reproduction se faisant en haute mer, le poisson disparait des côtes pendant l'hiver : il tourne donc l'[échine](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9chine) – c'est-à-dire [le dos](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tourner%20le%20dos) – à la Sainte-Catherine, avant de revenir – donc [reparaître](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/repara%C3%AEtre) – pour la Sainte-Blaise.
2. « [Aberliner](https://archive.org/stream/leberrycontribu01vachgoog#page/n372/mode/2up) » est un mot qui semblait signifier « acheminer », « approcher ». Puisque [saint André](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9%20(ap%C3%B4tre)) se fête le 30 novembre, ce proverbe rappelle que l'hiver n'arrive pas brusquement : il ne fait que s'annoncer fin novembre, et ne débute réellement qu'en décembre.
3. Un [bief](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bief#Histoire_des_biefs_ou_bisses_d.27irrigation_ou_des_moulins) est un canal amenant l'eau d'une rivière jusqu'à la roue d'un moulin. Si celui-ci gèle, la roue ne tourne plus et il est alors trop tard pour faire de la farine. Ce proverbe a donc le même sens que le précédent.
4. Les premiers cochons sont souvent tués début octobre.
5. « [Couétine](https://books.google.fr/books?ei=rKvTTu7cDcqesAa346XACg&ct=result&hl=fr&id=-IvhAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22%20sainte%20Catherine%20am%C3%A8ne%20la%20cou%C3%A9tine%22&q=cou%C3%A9tine#search_anchor) » est un mot franc-comtois désignant le gel, tout à fait adapté pour décrire la fin du mois de novembre qui voit souvent apparaître les premières gelées.
6. Voir le proverbe numéro 3.

Comment: Merci pour cette belle référence sur « aberliner » ! Oui, #6 est étrange. L'évènement que tu cites ne semble être qu'une anecdote sur sainte Catherine de Sienne ; j'ai du mal à trouver d'autres liens entre elle et la farine. On peut aussi imaginer simplement une analogie neige ↔ farine, mais je ne crois pas qu'elle fut très répandue.

Comment: Avec plaisir! Oui [Sienne](https://books.google.com/books?id=k3dTAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA241&ots=YViZnwZAds&dq=farine%20sainte-catherine&pg=PA241#v=onepage&q=farine%20sainte-catherine&f=false) complètement anecdotique; j'ai aussi pensé au début à la couétine p-e ds le sens d'une _coiffe_ pour les [_catherinettes_](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catherinettes), ou la couverture re: froid, etc. haha on aime l'anecdote! Le sarrasin, farine noire, récolté jusqu'à novembre. La roue dentelée de son supplice. Je pense que aberliner c'est [aber](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aber); j'ai vu _aberhavre_. Merci.